# Calculate the number of nearest neighbours in a particular lattice in $\mathbb R^d$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have been wondering about the following for a while now:

Can you construct a lattice in $L \subset \mathbb R^d$ such that the euclidean distance between any two nearest neighbours is $1$ and we have the property that $\textbf{0} \in L$. Also we require that the lattice is maximal in some sense - not sure how to write this maximality down but hopefully examples will help:

- In $d = 1$, clearly $\mathbb Z$ is such a lattice
- In $d=2$, I am thinking of a hexagonal lattice with all side lengths equal to 1.

Questions

1. Does such a lattice exist for $ d > 2$? Is there a name for it?
2. Is there a closed formula for the number of nearest neighbours, $N(d)$, in such a lattice? ($N(1) = 2, N(2) = 6, ... $)

Comment: It's out of current knowledge. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing

Comment: Also wiki lies about optimal results, but intro is okay.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can give natural measure of lattice maximality as density — number of points lying in some (big) cube relative to its volume (or, equivalently, volume of $\Bbb R^n/\Lambda)$. Another (more used) convention is to draw actual balls of diameter $1$ around points and calculate filled volume — I'll use this one, but they differ by only dimension dependent multiplicative constant — volume ratio of ball and cube. There's also more general question — what if we do not require our points to be an additive subgroup of $\Bbb R^n$, but only require that distance between them is $\geq 1$?

- $n=1$: obviously $\Bbb Z \subset \Bbb R$ gives what we want
- $n = 2$: hexagonal lattice is densest (Fejes-Toth theorem, 1940)
- $n = 3$: cubical lattice (equal to layer-alternating hexagonal lattice) is densest (Hayes, 1998)
- $n = 8, 24$: [E8 lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_lattice) and [Leech lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice) are densest (Viazovska, 2016)

All these constructions are most dense over all packings, not only lattice ones.

Little is known apart from it. There are some asymptotic bounds for $D(n)$ := maximal possible density:

- $D(n) > 2^{-n}$: obvious
- $D(N) > 2^{-n+1}$: Minkovski, 1901
- $D(n) < 2^{-Kn}, K \simeq 0.599$, Kabatianski, Levenstein, 1973
- $D(n) > C \cdot n \cdot log \,log\, n \, 2^{-n}$: Venkatesh, 2012

There's somewhat outdated (in terms of records) but very interesting book "Sphere Packings, Lattices and Groups" by J. H. Conway about all this business.

But, actually, situation is worse: even without requirement on some regularity, we do not know how many balls can touch given one! It's called [kissing number problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number_problem). Only in 6 dimensions definite number is known — 1, 2, 3, 4, 8 and 24, and except for [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-cell_honeycomb) optimal configuration is already listed above.